# Keras: Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to some images for a classification.

Here is my Python code but when I try to run it, Keras doesn't seem to find the images returning `Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.` and the deep leaning model is finally throwing the following error.

```
`ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0.`
```

How can we fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reorganize your dataset as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory).

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

In other words keras will assign class label for each image automatically depending the directory it is located in.

Comment: Thank you Vasil. I did but it is not working. If you have seen the datasets I shared, they are on two different folders. Inside the output folder, we have two separate folders named images and labels as i indicated it on my source code. I would be grateful if you could give a try and post a minimal working example if it works out for you.